# How do I check if a certain SQL statement is being run?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Using SQL Server Management Studio, how can check or see who is running a certain SQL statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server Management Studio you can use `Activity Monitor`. Right click on the root server item in Object Explorer or from the top panel. The *Processes* section contains info about the callers.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what your requirement is (i.e. you want to see a trace of all the times certain T-SQL was run) you may want to look at SQL Trace (Profiler will create a client-side trace and have a significant performance impact.  **Create a server-side trace** by scripting out the trace in Profiler and running it directly on the server instead of keeping the Profiler trace running.  If you need more info on this I can elaborate).  Or if you're on SQL Server 2008 or higher then you should be using Extended Events.

The SQL Trace event class is [`SQL:StmtCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189886.aspx).

The Extended Events event is `sql_statement_completed`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the stored procedure 'sp_who' or 'sp_who active'. This will show active processes

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in Profiler, you can find it under Tools->SQL Server Profiler.